# "Invalid Payload Error while Creating Azure Batch Linked Service in Terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-data-factory, linked-service, azure-batch-account

We are trying to create an Azure Data Factory Linked Service for an Azure Batch account using Terraform. However, there is no native resource available in Terraform documentation for creating an Azure Batch Linked Service directly. To work around this, we attempted to use a custom-linked service. But, we are encountering an "Invalid Payload" error with the type "AzureBatch." We need assistance in resolving this issue and successfully creating the Azure Batch Linked Service using Terraform. Any guidance or solutions would be highly appreciated.

Reference:- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.datafactory/factories/linkedservices?pivots=deployment-language-terraform#azurebatchlinkedservice-2

[image]

Comment: Can you provide the code here instead of image. @Karandeep Singh

Comment: Hi@Jahnavi
this is the code
###
`resource "azurerm_data_factory_linked_custom_service" "example" {
  name                 = "azurebatch1"
  data_factory_id      = azurerm_data_factory.example.id
  type                 = "AzureBatch"
  description          = "test description"
  type_properties_json = <<JSON
{
  "connectionString":"${data.azurerm_storage_account.example.primary_connection_string}"
}
JSON

  parameters = {
    "foo" : "bar"
    "Env" : "Test"
  }

  annotations = [
    "test1",
    "test2",
    "test3"
  ]
}`

Answer (score 1):

According to the sample template from terraform registry, I checked your code and tried to create Azure Batch linked service in my environment using  [`azurerm_data_factory_linked_custom_service`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/data_factory_linked_custom_service#argument-reference) resource and was able to run it successfully as follows.

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "main" {
  name     = "example-resources"
  location = "West Europe"
}
resource "azurerm_data_factory" "main" {
  name                = "examplejambar"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.main.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.main.name
  identity {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }
}
resource "azurerm_storage_account" "main" {
  name                     = "examplelocker"
  resource_group_name      = azurerm_resource_group.main.name
  location                 = azurerm_resource_group.main.location
  account_kind             = "BlobStorage"
  account_tier             = "Standard"
  account_replication_type = "LRS"
}
resource "azurerm_data_factory_linked_custom_service" "main" {
  name                 = "mainsample"
  data_factory_id      = azurerm_data_factory.main.id
  type                 = "AzureBlobStorage"
  description          = "test description"
  type_properties_json = <<JSON
{
 "connectionString":"${azurerm_storage_account.main.primary_connection_string}"
}
JSON

  parameters = {
    "foo" : "bar"
    "Env" : "Test"
  }

  annotations = [
    "test1",
    "test2",
    "test3"
  ]
}
```

***Initialized & validated the configuration:***

[image]

***Executed*** `terraform plan`:

[image]

***Executed*** `terraform apply`:

[image]

***Deployed successfully:***

[image]

Comment: Hi Jahnavi
thanks for your suggestion but the example that you have provided it will create a linked service for blob storage not for batch account.
we want to create a linked service for batch account, please see the description carefully.
Thanks

Comment: But in the connection string I can see that it is linking to storage account. How are you trying to link it with the batch account? @KarandeepSingh

Comment: okay, so can u give me the solution for this, I want to link it with the batch account

Comment: Did you try adding the connection string of batch account under `connection_string` property. @KarandeepSingh

Comment: We have found the solution for this.
There is no need to provide a connection string.

Answer (score 0):

The error `is Invalid linked service payload, the "typeProperties" nested in payload is null..` shows that you have an issue with `"connectionString":"${data.azurerm_storage_account.example.primary_connection_string}"` config line.

Please double check that you have needed `azurerm_storage_account`, and `data.azurerm_storage_account.example.primary_connection_string` return correct connection string.

Comment: yes @zombi_man , so can u please give me a solution for this

Comment: what should be the correct value for the string if we are creating a linked service for a batch account?

Comment: @KarandeepSingh, if you don't have storage account, please check the answer of @jahnavi and add `resource azurerm_storage_account` to your terraform config

Comment: we have a storage account and batch account is using that storage account, but now we want to link that batch account with the data factory using a linked service.

Comment: ok, if you already have it please use the correct data resource for getting proper `connection string`. 
you can use `terraform console` command and run something like `data.azurerm_storage_account.example.primary_connection_string` and you should have the right `connection string`, if no - you need to update your terraform config. I believe you can check the connection string in the Azure UI.

Comment: We have found the solution for this.